# How to efficiently concatenate data frames with different column sets in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with different but overlaping column sets. I want to concatenate them in a way that pandas does but it is **very inefficient** in spark.

```
X:
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4

Y:
   A  C
0  5  7
1  6  8

pd.concat(X, Y):
   A   B   C
0  1   3 NaN
1  2   4 NaN
0  5 NaN   7
1  6 NaN   8
```

I tried to use Spark SQL to do it...

```
select A, B, null as C from X union all select A, null as B, C from Y
```

... and **it is extremely slow**. I applied this query to two tables with sizes: (79 rows, 17330 columns) and (92 rows, 16 columns). It took **129s** running on Spark 1.62, **319s** on Spark 2.01 and 1.2s on pandas.
Why is it so slow? Is this some kind of bug? **Can it be done faster using spark?**

EDIT:
I tried to do it programatically as in here: [how to union 2 spark dataframes with different amounts of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758045/how-to-union-2-spark-dataframes-with-different-amounts-of-columns) - it's even slower.

It **seems that the problem is adding null columns** maybe it can be solved somehow differently or this part could be made faster?

Comment: a) How do you read data? b) How did you configure the cluster?

Comment: It's just a testing setup so I run standalone spark instance on my laptop through ./bin/pyspark. I preprocess the data in python and then call `X = sc.parallelize(list_of_rows).toDF(column_names)` to make it into data frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to union 2 spark dataframes with different amounts of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758045/how-to-union-2-spark-dataframes-with-different-amounts-of-columns)

Comment: The emphasis is on **efficiently**. The solution in your link is as slow as mine.