# Union two DataFrame using spark 2.x with different schema/dataTypes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to merge multiple hive tables using spark where some of the columns with the same name have different data types especially string and bigint.

My final table (`hiveDF`) should have schema like below-

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
|         col_name         | data_type  | comment  |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
| announcementtype         | bigint     |          |
| approvalstatus           | string     |          |
| capitalrate              | double     |          |
| cash                     | double     |          |
| cashinlieuprice          | double     |          |
| costfactor               | double     |          |
| createdby                | string     |          |
| createddate              | string     |          |
| currencycode             | string     |          |
| declarationdate          | string     |          |
| declarationtype          | bigint     |          |
| divfeerate               | double     |          |
| divonlyrate              | double     |          |
| dividendtype             | string     |          |
| dividendtypeid           | bigint     |          |
| editedby                 | string     |          |
| editeddate               | string     |          |
| exdate                   | string     |          |
| filerecordid             | string     |          |
| frequency                | string     |          |
| grossdivrate             | double     |          |
| id                       | bigint     |          |
| indicatedannualdividend  | string     |          |
| longtermrate             | double     |          |
| netdivrate               | double     |          |
| newname                  | string     |          |
| newsymbol                | string     |          |
| note                     | string     |          |
| oldname                  | string     |          |
| oldsymbol                | string     |          |
| paydate                  | string     |          |
| productid                | bigint     |          |
| qualifiedratedollar      | double     |          |
| qualifiedratepercent     | double     |          |
| recorddate               | string     |          |
| sharefactor              | double     |          |
| shorttermrate            | double     |          |
| specialdivrate           | double     |          |
| splitfactor              | double     |          |
| taxstatuscodeid          | bigint     |          |
| lastmodifieddate         | timestamp  |          |
| active_status            | boolean    |          |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
```

This final table (`hiveDF`) schema can be made with below JSON-

```
{
"id": -2147483647,
"productId": 150816,
"dividendTypeId": 2,
"dividendType": "Dividend/Capital Gain",
"payDate": null,
"exDate": "2009-03-25",
"oldSymbol": "ILAAX",
"newSymbol": "ILAAX",
"oldName": "",
"newName": "",
"grossDivRate": 0.115,
"shortTermRate": 0,
"longTermRate": 0,
"splitFactor": 0,
"shareFactor": 0,
"costFactor": 0,
"cashInLieuPrice": 0,
"cash": 0,
"note": "0",
"createdBy": "Yahoo",
"createdDate": "2009-08-03T06:44:19.677-05:00",
"editedBy": "Yahoo",
"editedDate": "2009-08-03T06:44:19.677-05:00",
"netDivRate": null,
"divFeeRate": null,
"specialDivRate": null,
"approvalStatus": null,
"capitalRate": null,
"qualifiedRateDollar": null,
"qualifiedRatePercent": null,
"declarationDate": null,
"declarationType": null,
"currencyCode": null,
"taxStatusCodeId": null,
"announcementType": null,
"frequency": null,
"recordDate": null,
"divOnlyRate": 0.115,
"fileRecordID": null,
"indicatedAnnualDividend": null
}
```

I am doing something like below-

```
var hiveDF = spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from final_destination_tableName")
var newDataDF = spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from incremental_table_1 where id > 866000")
```

My incremental table (`newDataDF`) has some columns with different data types. I have around 10 incremental tables where somewhere `bigint` and the same in other table as string so can't be sure if I do typecast. Typecast may be easy but I am not sure on which type should I do since multiple tables are there. I am looking for any approach where without typecast I can do.

For an example incremental table is something like below-

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
|         col_name         | data_type  | comment  |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
| announcementtype         | string     |          |
| approvalstatus           | string     |          |
| capitalrate              | string     |          |
| cash                     | double     |          |
| cashinlieuprice          | double     |          |
| costfactor               | double     |          |
| createdby                | string     |          |
| createddate              | string     |          |
| currencycode             | string     |          |
| declarationdate          | string     |          |
| declarationtype          | string     |          |
| divfeerate               | string     |          |
| divonlyrate              | double     |          |
| dividendtype             | string     |          |
| dividendtypeid           | bigint     |          |
| editedby                 | string     |          |
| editeddate               | string     |          |
| exdate                   | string     |          |
| filerecordid             | string     |          |
| frequency                | string     |          |
| grossdivrate             | double     |          |
| id                       | bigint     |          |
| indicatedannualdividend  | string     |          |
| longtermrate             | double     |          |
| netdivrate               | string     |          |
| newname                  | string     |          |
| newsymbol                | string     |          |
| note                     | string     |          |
| oldname                  | string     |          |
| oldsymbol                | string     |          |
| paydate                  | string     |          |
| productid                | bigint     |          |
| qualifiedratedollar      | string     |          |
| qualifiedratepercent     | string     |          |
| recorddate               | string     |          |
| sharefactor              | double     |          |
| shorttermrate            | double     |          |
| specialdivrate           | string     |          |
| splitfactor              | double     |          |
| taxstatuscodeid          | string     |          |
| lastmodifieddate         | timestamp  |          |
| active_status            | boolean    |          |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+--+
```

I'm doing this union for table something like below-

```
var combinedDF = hiveDF.unionAll(newDataDF)
```

but no luck. I tried to give final schema as below but no luck-

```
val rows = newDataDF.rdd
val newDataDF2 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, hiveDF.schema)
var combinedDF = hiveDF.unionAll(newDataDF2)
combinedDF.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("orc.compress", "snappy").orc("/apps/hive/warehouse/" + database + "/" + tableLower + "_temp")
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758045/how-to-perform-union-on-two-dataframes-with-different-amounts-of-columns-in-spar%00), I tried below-

```
var combinedDF = sparkSession.read.json(hiveDF.toJSON.union(newDataDF.toJSON).rdd)
```

Finally I am trying to write into table like above but no luck, plz help me-

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @ChandanRay
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this situation while merging an incremental table with the existing table. There are generally 2 cases to handle

**1. Incremental data with extra column:**

This can be solved by normal merging process which you are trying here.

**2. Incremental data with same column name but different schema:**

This is the tricky one. One easy solution is to convert bot the data to toJSON and do union 
`hiveDF.toJSON.union(newDataDF.toJSON)`. This however will cause json schema merging and will change the existing schema. For eg: If the column `a:Long` in the table and `a:String` in the incremental table, after merging the final schema will be a:String. There is no way to evade this if you want to do json union.

The alternate to this is to have strict schema check for the incremental data. You test whether the incremental table has the same schema that the hive table, if the schema differs don't merge.

This is however little too stringent as for real time data it is pretty hard to put schema enforcement.

So the way I solved this is to have a separate enrichment process before merging. The process actually checks the schema and if the incoming column can be upgraded/downgraded to the current hive table schema it does that.

Essentially it iterate over the incoming delta, for each row convert that to the correct schema. This is little expensive but provides very good guarantee for the data correctness. In case the process fails to convert a row. I sideline the row and raise an alarm so that the data could be validated manually for any bug in the upstream system which is generating the data.

This is the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L399)  I use to validate whether the two schemas are mergable of not.