# how to use union of two dataframes which have different column numbers pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, union

I have two dataframes:

**df1** which consists of column from col1 to col7

**df2** which consists of column from col1 to col9

I need to perform union of these two dataframes,
however it fails because of the two extra columns.

Any idea what other function can be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform union on two DataFrames with different amounts of columns in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758045/how-to-perform-union-on-two-dataframes-with-different-amounts-of-columns-in-spar)

Comment: clear duplicate please consider closing the question.. This is already explained in the answer of the link - what's wrong with it? You should really try to understand the code there

Answer (score -1):

Add two columns to `df2` and then go ahead with the union.

Import -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
```

If `col8` and `col9` are **numbers** then do -

```
new_df = df2.withColumn("col8", lit(float('nan'))).withColumn("col9", lit(float('nan')))
```

Or if col8 and col9 are **strings** then do -

```
new_df = df2.withColumn("col8", lit("")).withColumn("col9", lit(""))
```

Now union the new_df with df1.