# Reading multiple CSV files from Azure blob storage using Databricks PySpark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How to read multiple CSV files with different columns and file path names and make a single dataframe.

Here is an example just 2 paths. However there are many paths based on `frn` and `filename`.

```
"wasbs://containername@accountname.blob.core.windows.net/blobname/frn=xyz123/filename=file1/myfile34.csv"

"wasbs://containername@accountname.blob.core.windows.net/blobname/frn=abc567/filename=file2/myfile84.csv"
```

1. Columns can be concatenated and filled with NA if there is no value present.
2. Adding new columns based on `frn` and filename as mentioned in path with respective dataframe of CSV file.
3. In each `filename` folder there is only one single CSV is present but there is multiple `filename` folder under each single `frn` folder.

For example:

```
myfile34.csv
   a  b frn      filename
0  3  4 xyz123   file1   
1  4  5 xyz123   file1
2  5  6 xyz123   file1

myfile84.csv    
   a  c frn      filename
0  1  3 abc567   file2
1  2  4 abc567   file2
2  3  5 abc567   file2

final df
  a b  c    frn      filename
0 3 4  NA   xyz123   file1  
1 4 5  NA   xyz123   file1  
2 5 6  NA   xyz123   file1  
3 1 NA 3    abc567   file2
4 2 NA 4    abc567   file2
5 3 NA 5.   abc567   file2
```

I tried this :

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

path = "wasbs://containername@accountname.blob.core.windows.net/blobname/*/*/"
df = ks.read_csv(path, sep="','",header='infer')
```

but how can i concat these different `csv` files and create new columns (like `frn` and `filename`)  as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform union on two DataFrames with different amounts of columns in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758045/how-to-perform-union-on-two-dataframes-with-different-amounts-of-columns-in-spar)

Comment: @blackbishop Not completely!, Actually there are multiple csv files which is stored in different paths.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation/workaround would be to use `parquet` file format, as its one of the best formats for cases of schema evolution.

*Ofcourse, I dont deny the fact, we can do with few more steps in pyspark itself, which wont be straight forward.*

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging

[image]

```
# Write both dataframes in same location, utilizing append, in parquet format.
df_1.write.mode('append').parquet('<URI_HERE>/out')
df_2.write.mode('append').parquet('<URI_HERE>/out')

# Note: mergeSchema will mege files with different structures, and merge common columns and fill Null values for non-intersecting columns.
spark.read.option('mergeSchema', True).parquet('<URI_HERE>/out').show()
```

[image]

Happy learning!

Comment: I have many csv files (not just 2) and there is no option to modify format of file from csv to parquet.

Comment: @vsb, I see that you use kolas in databricks. So, of course there is an option to convert the dataframe to parquet https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Comment: @vsb, as you know the file structures are different from one another, so, you have to create the dataframes from each CSV file. So, just iterate through a loop. If you create it on top of the root folder, how will it be able to decide whats the structure it needs to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
val myDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/client/ABC*.gz")

myDFCsv.show()
myDFCsv.head()
myDFCsv.count()


//////////////////////////////////////////
// If you also need to load the filename
val myDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/client/ABC*.gz")
   .withColumn("file_name",input_file_name())


myDFCsv.show(false)
myDFCsv.head()
myDFCsv.count()
```